# Merge 2 of 3 labels to Production branch

Tags: tfs, merge, label

We have a development branch where the developers check in their workspaces when the a task is finished. They label the check-in. Let's say 3 developers, with labels 1, 2, and 3. Now I want to merge just Label 1 and label 3. 
My question is, won't label 3 have all the code from label 1 and 2, also? 
It seems to me there is no good way to omit label 2 from the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, labels include a crosssection across the codebase (though since they're scoped they might not include all files technically). The only way to merge Label 1 and 3 is to look at the respective change sets and select the ones to merge, this process is called [cherry-pick-merging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/01/19/what-is-a-cherry-pick-merge-and-why-do-you-recommend-against-them.aspx). If the changes are neatly combined into a set of consecutive changesets, then this might work.

You can look at the Changeset number that belongs to the files you want to merge in that label (there might be multiple changeset versions associated to a label) and merge the specific changesets.

Relying on [cherry-pick-merging is dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/01/19/what-is-a-cherry-pick-merge-and-why-do-you-recommend-against-them.aspx), since it can be very hard to actually merge two changesets without taking additional changes that happened in between. Either you'll accidentally take too much into the target branch, or the changesets rely on changes in other changesets which you might not be considering to merge.

Unless the team is fully aware that the changes are going to be cherry-picked and develop with this in mind (shelving, checking in working features as single changesets, applying [design patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check in separate modules that can be easily merged with existing functionality), then it's safer to merge up to a specific changeset or to use feature branches.

Another technique to selectively 'merge' features is to put [feature-toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) in your code. Essentially allowing you to release feature 1+2+3 with feature 2 turned off.

Comment: The first thing I thought of was branching by feature, but when I presented this to the developers at my Presentation, they all balked, saying it was "too hard". It seems obvious to me that making a branch for each work item would be ideal. It can be merged into the Dev branch at will and I can pick the branches that are approved for Staging and merge only those. Conflicts won't be a problem, and there shouldn't be any "missing pieces" from other branches. Ummmm... I _think_ there shouldn't be, since they all start with the same code.

Comment: A feature branch per work item might be overkill. When you are certain that a feature will get delivered it's usually more expensive and risky to setup additional branches than it is to commit them to the dev branch directly. For larger features you can use feature branches. There is overhead and it can be hard especially when there is a need to switch between branches often.

Comment: I think you missed the point that changes (branches) need to be moved to Staging independently. If there are 5 features, maybe numbers 1, 3, and 4 are put in, then #5, then #2. The order is not known in advance. Developers will not be working on multiple branches at once. I just need a way for a manager to migrate code feature by feature, based on his own whims ;)

Comment: For such situation a plugin Architecture or Feature toggles a better solution. branching usually isnt.